# How to calculate launch angle for tangentially launched satellites?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, rocket-science

What is the value of theta for a satellite not falling back to the Earth if it is launched from the direction tangent to the surface of the Earth? I have found the escape velocity which is 11.18km/s, and initial speed for the satellite which ensure it doesn't fall back to Earth, which is 7.4km/s. Shall I solve the questions using conservation of angular momentum? Or centrifugal force? It is an elliptical orbit.

Comment: An object in an orbit will always returns to the point where it accelerated last. So when you try to launch a craft with a single, instant impulse, the craft will always return to the start location. To reach an orbit from a surface, you either need progressive acceleration or you need at least two impulses (like with a [hohmann transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer))

Comment: Hi phillipp. Yea i have searched about the Hohmann Transfer however i cant really relate the calculations to the angle of the launch of satellite where it does not fall off.

Comment: As I said there is no such angle or vector, because any trajectory you can reach through an instant impulse from the ground will either escape, crash into the ground or would return to the exact start location (when there would be no atmosphere - with atmosphere you would also get a crash).

Comment: Yes there is a literal value of angle for this case just that the theory behind it is not understood.Anyway the atmospheric friction is not taken into account.So how do we relate the angular momentum and the angle?

Comment: (showing a complete lack of knowledge about orbital mechanics) Does the launch azimuth (relative to Earth's rotation), combined w/ Coriolus effects, allow for the possibility of settling into an orbit?

Comment: What is the theta you are looking for? Argument of perigee? Longitude? Right ascension of the ascending node? True anomaly? What? Being a rocket scientist myself, I can tell you that the theory behind these things is well understood. Please describe exactly what you are asking

Comment: Hi Jim.The question is(If the satellite is launched at angle theta from the tangent direction to the surface of earth,with the speed found which is 7.4km/s, find the range of theta values which the satellite will go into an orbit around the earth;ie:It will not fall back to earth or fly off to solar system)

Comment: I'm pretty sure such an angle doesn't exist. The velocity for a circular orbit at the surface is 7.9km/s. Any more elliptic orbit would need a larger velocity at the surface initial launch because that would be the perigee. Any lower speed would be an orbit that goes to a lower altitude, which is inside the surface. Furthermore, no orbit can be established by only a boost at the surface with an angle other than tangent to the surface. Any other angle would mean that the craft must come up through the surface to return to that point

Comment: Hi Jim.Sorry that i never make myself clear.The velocity is 7.4 because the satellite is launched from the rocket 500km above the surface tangent to the earth.Anyway my lecturer gave a hint that it can be solved using conservation of angular momentum

Comment: Oh, well we can't solve this for you if it's a homework question

Comment: Oh this isnt a homework.This is a PBL question that require group discussion with lecturer.My

Comment: Just to argue/challenge Philipp and Jim's points about the fact that the satellite would go in an orbit that returns to the launching point: what about effects due to drag? Is it then possible to work against the satellite by drag until its orbit becomes an ideal shape? (Beyond the scope of the question?) Am I right in assuming that the satellite starts close enough to the Earth's surface to deal with drag?